# Can I use pymongo library to connect to firestore DB?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, pymongo

I have an application written in python using pymongo library to connect to AWS document DB . Now I'm trying to host it on GCP and see that we have firestore db available, but the library to connect and work with firestore is different.

Can I somehow use pymongo to operate with firestore?

Comment: Pymongo is for mongo engine. Firestore is not a mongo engine. So, it can't work.

Comment: Is there a python SDK you are aware that can act as abstract layer? I saw something wrt GO https://gocloud.dev/howto/docstore @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: You can use NDB https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb